Harmonic function and the method separation of variables
I wanted to find harmonic function $u(x,y)$ in a square $\Omega$ = {$ 0<x< \pi, \; 0 < y < \pi $} with boundary conditions $u(0, y) = 0, \;u(\pi, y) = y, \;u(x,0) =0, \;u(x, \pi) = x + \sin(3x)$. I wanted to use method separation of variables.
The partial solution which I got has the form
$$u(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi}xy + \sin(\beta x) (C\sinh(\beta y) + D\cosh(\beta y)) $$
I don't know how to evaluate it and get solution which is correct and satisfy the boundary condition.

Your partial solution already satisfies the boundary condition $u(0,y)=0$. Let's examine the other three:
$$
u(x,0)=0 \implies D\sin(\beta x)=0 \implies D=0, \tag{1} 
$$
$$
u(x,\pi)=x+\sin(3x) \implies \frac{1}{\pi}x\pi+C\sin(\beta x)
\sinh(\beta\pi)=x+\sin(3x) 
$$
$$
\implies \beta=3\quad\text{and}\quad C=\frac{1}{\sinh(3\pi)}. \tag{2} 
$$
With the values of $\beta, C$ and $D$ determined in $(1)$ and $(2)$, the remaining boundary condition is automatically satisfied:
$$
u(\pi,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\pi y+\sin(3\pi)\frac{\sinh(3y)}{\sinh(3\pi)}=y. \tag{3}
$$
Therefore, the final solution is
$$
u(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}xy+\sin(3x)\frac{\sinh(3y)}{\sinh(3\pi)}. \tag{4}
$$
